# Powershell script call functions

Tags: function, powershell

trying to do something insanely simple in PS but for some odd reason it is just not playing ball. My PS script looks like:

For some reason its complaining about the fact that:

***enableMSDTC : The term 'enableMSDTC' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.***

Am I not allowed to do this? I have to have a separate script file for each function?

Thanks in advance, DS.

```
    param
    (
        [string]$folder = $(throw 'Local folder to map to is required.')
    )

    begin
    {
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
    }
    process
    {
$hasDrive = Test-Path -Path "D:\"

    if ($hasDrive -eq $true) {
        echo "Enabling MSDTC settings..."
        enableMSDTC    
    }

    Function enableMSDTC() {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "LuTransactions" -Value "1"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "NetworkDtcAccess" -Value "1"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "NetworkDtcAccessAdmin" -Value "1"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "NetworkDtcAccessClients" -Value "1"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "NetworkDtcAccessInbound" -Value "1"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "NetworkDtcAccessOutbound" -Value "1"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "NetworkDtcAccessTransactions" -Value "1"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security" -Name "NetworkDtcAccessXaTransactions" -Value "1"        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function before you try to call it.

Comment: Dear god didn't realise it was procedural! Thank you.

Comment: Bit me in the butt all the time when I started. :)

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is an **interpreted** language, which means commands are parsed in order (top down) at run time.

You can't call a function or refer to a variable before you define it.

Comment: Well, just to be pedantic, Interpreted vs. Compiled language doesn't determine this. For example, VBScript is an interpreted language and you can put functions at the end of a file with no problem at all. It simply depends on the way that the interpreter behaves.